# What is proper syntax for wildcard driven filter rules file for rsync?

Tags: rsync

I am trying to use a filter rules file that uses wildcards for include/exclude lines to drive what gets included and excluded for running rsync to backup a server.

I am using the command line like:

```
rsync -avzh --filter="merge rsync_backup_filter" / user@backupserver:/backup-data
```

where rsync_backup_filter is currently something like

```
+ /var
+ /var/www
+ /var/www/webapp1/***
+ /var/www/webapp2/***
- /var/www/*/repo
+ /home/***
+ /etc/***
- *
```

but that filter rule syntax above is not quite right because the results don't actually match what I am intending. The `repo` sub folder is not excluded as I am trying to achieve.

- I want to be able to use something like the last entry to say exclude anything not explicitly (using wildcards) included in the rules above
- I want to be able to include certain paths (in the example above including webapp paths) and indicate that all files and folders below that point should be included but also be able to add exclusions within that previous wildcard (in the example above I want to exclude the `repo` subdir in any webapp path, so essentially saying "all except" in certain paths
- Above is just a snippet and the longer version of the file would be a full backup strategy for the server from the root on

What is correct way to do structure the filter rules file and proper way to use wildcards to achieve what I've described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rules constitute an ordered set and evaluation continues until the first match occurs.  So, all repo folders will be excluded, if you move the exclude rule up - at least to line #3.

Comment: Doh! - I was so close!